# Make a list item Non editable once the Issue status is set to "Closed"

Tags: list, sharepoint, listitem

I have a SharePoint list to store list items to track an issue. There is a drop down called "Issue Status" which has values - "Active", "In-Progress" & "Closed".

I need help in making the list item non editable when the issue is marked as "**Closed**" in the drop down.

Also a help on making the drop down show only "**Active**" when the new list item is created would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has two parts.

> I need help in making the list item non editable when the issue is
>   marked as "Closed" in the drop down.

There are multiple ways to do this. You can use JS Link to control the rendering of the edit form. You can write your code logic to show the edit form in read-only mode once the status changes to "Closed". You can download [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) sample and modify it for your needs.

> Also a help on making the drop down show only "Active" when the new
>   list item is created would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Similar to the previous one you can add a JS Link to new form to remove all options except "Active" in the drop down.

Read more about JS Link [here](http://www.kaptyn.com/SharePoint/customising-new-form/).